# Schedule Post - Displaying Some Content only for Some time or any time in future or Repitative

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display some content only for some time or some days
I have start time, start date, end time and end date in database so that when the data is fetched from database this time and dates should be checked and display the content accordingly

My code that i have tried

```
$startDateTime = strtotime($result['StartDate']." ".$result['StartTime']);
$endDateTime = strtotime($result['EndDate']." ".$result['EndTime']);
$now = time();

echo "START : ".$startDateTime;
echo "<br/>END : ".$endDateTime;
echo "<br/>CURRENT : ".$now;
if($now >= $startDateTime && $now <= $endDateTime){
echo $result['content'];

}
```

But its not working its displaying the content every time

Please Help Me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the time() function - try creating '$now' as strtotime("now").

Also, as a debugging step, it probably would have helped you to echo the comparisons to see if they evaluated the way that you expected.

Actually - I just tried your code exactly as it was...Except that I had hard coded values for the starting and ending dates and times.  And it worked, so switching to use strtotime("now") will probably not make a difference.

What are the values that were printed out?  You didn't tell us.

So VoronoiPotato is probably right...The values you are storing for StartDate/StartTime and EndDate/EndTime must have something wrong with them.

What is the output of your program if you change it like this (to add more debugging):

```
$startDateTime = $result['StartDate'] . " " . $result['StartTime'];
$endDateTime = $result['EndDate'] . " " . $result['EndTime'];
$now = time();

echo "START : " . $startDateTime."<br />\n";
echo "END : " . $endDateTime . "<br />\n";

$startDateTime = strtotime($startDateTime);
$endDateTime = strtotime($endDateTime);

echo "Start as time: " . $startDateTime . "<br />\n";
echo "End as time: " . $endDateTime . "<br />\n";

echo "CURRENT : " . $now . "\n";

if (($now >= $startDateTime) && ($now <= $endDateTime)) {
    echo $result['content'];
}
```

Comment: no its not working, The content is not displaying when the start time is less than current time

Comment: But what is being displayed as (START, END, Start as time, End as time, and CURRENT)?  Those values are what I wanted to know.  Because, they should indicate what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

output a list of your $result['StartDate']." ".$result['StartTime'] I think you'll find that it might be leaving off leading 0's or something which would give it trouble casting it as a time.