# How to display some content only for some time or some days

Tags: php

I want to display some content only for some time or some days or repitative

the start time , start date , end date and end date will be stored in database

so when the current time is in between start date, start time, end date and end time the content should display

How to achieve this... Please Help Me

Thanks in advance

Comment: and the code you have tired is? and the issue with the code is?

Comment: Have you looked at PHP's date(...)?

Comment: probably don't need date() but the relevant db functions, not that we even know what db it is.

Comment: since its under PHP, learn how to use SQL, do queries from PHP according to the conditions and rules that meet your criteria, @Dagon comment is on spot, on this site we help to resolve specific problems, we don't write code for others, try to do it, if you have any problem be sure there's thousand of people ready to help

Comment: please dont post the same question again, this time with even less detail :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828274/schedule-post-displaying-some-content-only-for-some-time-or-any-time-in-future

Comment: you should have to take a look on the `date()` as well on the `strtotime()`, both of these functions help you to achieve that you want..

Answer (score 1):

There aren't a lot of details in this question to go on, but let's say you're using the MySQL database, and you have a table like you've described:

```
mytable:
  start_time TIME
  start_date DATE
  end_date DATE
  content TEXT
```

So, you could make use of MySQL's [date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to help you select the appropriate content, and possibly use PHP's `date` as well, as suggested in the comments.

For example, let's say you wanted to construct a query that retrieved content for "today".

You could use something like:

```
SELECT content FROM mytable
WHERE CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
      AND start_time <= CURRENT_TIME
```

Have a look at the [PHP date function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) so that you can construct a parameterized query with alternate values.